# How can I implement private Org-wide defaults access to draft Knowledge articles?

Tags: knowledge, owd, lightning-knowledge

My client wants to allow some users to see only draft knowledge articles created by them.
I assummed that I could implement this using sharing setting and set Knowledge object to Private Organization Wide Defaults.
To my surprize Knowledge object is not listed in Sharing settings to setup OWD.
Is there are any way to implement private Org-wide defaults access to draft articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Knowledge Settings and Check `Use standard Salesforce sharing` checkbox in Sharing Settings section

[image]

After this is applied, the Knowledge object becomes available in Sharing Settings

[image]